# Android Studio installation on Ubuntu 12.04 fails to initialize

Tags: android, linux, ubuntu-12.04, android-studio

I get this error while trying to install Android Studio on Ubuntu 12.04 .

```
Plugin com.intellij failed to initialize and will be disabled.
null
Please restart Android Studio.
```

Anybody has tried to run Android Studio on Linux yet ?

Edit : Okay guys , had to update my Java , instructions for it are https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Java ; and after that it worked.

Edit2: Forget to mention , after updating ; go to terminal and type echo $JAVA_HOME ; and then go to the bin folder of IDEA ; open idea.sh and add `export IDEA_JDK='value_you_found_from_echo_java_home'`. This line should be just before `if [-n $IDED_JDK ..`

Comment: I'm sure *someone's* tried.

Comment: The error message says to restart Android Studio.  Do that.

Comment: And you think I haven't done that ! Basically , I am using ./studio.sh to run the Android Studio , and this message keeps creeping again and again .

Comment: Well , the best answer from google was ;http://devnet.jetbrains.com/thread/441187

Comment: I'm getting same error on my ubuntu 10.10 machine.

Comment: Okay , for those who thinks I have messed up the JAVA_HOME variable ; I put the variable value that I found through echo $JAVA_HOME in the studio.sh file . Before that the Android start screen would not come and said to configure the JDK path . However , the startscreen comes but I am stuck with that above problem .

Comment: @MotiurRahman Try running `export JDK_HOME = <path to jdk>`.