# How to install Android Studio on Ubuntu?

Tags: android, ubuntu, android-studio

I have to install Android Studio on Ubuntu and I have used [this link](https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html) to download Android Studio.

Is there any easy way to install Studio on Ubuntu?

Comment: extract downloaded zip file and run studio.sh from bin folder.

Comment: Just unzip it to where u have permissions then get the orscle jdk and set $studio_jdk to $oracleRoot/bin then look at "studio.sh" to ensure it picks up the env var for oracle jdk.

Comment: Download and extract the tar.gz file. Read and follow the file called "Install-Linux-tar.txt".

Comment: See https://blog.sudobits.com/2014/07/28/getting-started-with-android-studio-on-ubuntu-linux-1404-lts/

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Download the Linux SDK from the [Android website](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html#Other).
Copy the folder to whereever you want to extract the contents.
Open a terminal there, and then run:

```
sudo apt-get install unzip
sudo tar xvzf android-studio-ide-135.1641136-linux.zip
cd android-studio-ide-135.1641136-linux
./studio.sh
```

---

JDK 1.7 is required for Studio 1.0 onwards:

1. Download the ubuntu zip from the [d.android.com](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html#Other) and repeat the steps from above
2. Download the jdk 1.7 by executing the following commands in terminal as mentioned [webupd8](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/01/install-oracle-java-jdk-7-in-ubuntu-via.html):

   ```
   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get install oracle-java7-installer
   ```
3. Open Android Studio and install the SDK tools.

Caveats:

1. If your system has a 32 bit processor, use [Platform Tools r23.0.1](https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/platform-tools_r23.0.1-linux.zip).
   Refer to this [bug](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=196866) for details.

Note: If you are running a 64-bit version of Ubuntu, you need to install some 32-bit libraries with the following command:

```
$ sudo apt-get install libc6:i386 libncurses5:i386 libstdc++6:i386 lib32z1
```

Source: - [linux-32-bit-librarie](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/linux-32-bit-libraries)s

Comment: OpenJDK 6 is not supported. Please use Oracle Java or newer OpenJDK

Comment: do you have different JDK's in your system?or are you just starting android development?

Comment: try this http://www.webupd8.org/2012/01/install-oracle-java-jdk-7-in-ubuntu-via.html to install jdk

Comment: i have installed both OpenJDK Java 6 Runtime and OpenJDK Java 7 Runtime, but still getting same issue

Comment: You have installed runtimes i.e. JRE.You need complete JDKs.

Comment: also check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16578810/android-studio-installation-on-ubuntu-12-04-fails-to-initialize?rq=1

Comment: can i update current apk using Android Studio those i have created using eclipse ADT ?

Comment: yes,Studio supports importing projects from eclipse.

Comment: ok, thanks i will check soon .. and one more thing where can i get tv, wear, glass, car icons those i saw in Android Studio at start up !

Comment: NOTE: INSTEAD OF studio.sh TYPE ./studio.sh on terminal.

Comment: @Droidekas This answer should be updated to include the oracle-java8-installer

Comment: In case the above download link doesn't redirect to linux binaries in windows machine, use this [link](https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html#linux-bundle)

Comment: `sudo tar xvzf android-studio-ide-135.1641136-linux.zip` of course this won't work. Did you mean `sudo unzip android-studio-ide-135.1641136-linux.zip`?

Comment: the studio.sh file is in the bin folder.

Answer (score 58):

Below are the steps to install Android Studio in Ubuntu system:

**1. Install JDK 6 or later**

First, install Oracle JDK 8 (although you could also choose OpenJDK but it has some UI/performance issues) using [WebUpd8 PPA](https://launchpad.net/%7Ewebupd8team/+archive/ubuntu/java).

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer
sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-set-default
```

To make sure, it’s installed successfully, open a terminal and type (you should get the version number of the jdk you’ve installed e.g javac 1.8.0_11)

```
javac -version
```

**2. Download and install Android Studio**

[Download the Android Studio package for Linux](https://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html) and extract it somewhere (e.g home directory).
Then type :

```
cd android-studio/bin
./studio.sh
```

**3. Install SDK Platforms**

You need to install some SDK before you jump into building android apps. `Click on Configure -> SDK Manage`r to open Android SDK Manager. Select the latest API (to test against target build, e.g API 19 (Android 4.4.2)) and some packages in Extras (Android Support Library and Android Support Repository). Then install the selected packages.

Comment: @GrlsHu,Android does not support jdk 8 yet,jdk 7 and 6 would still be needed

Comment: @GrIsHu where can i get tv, wear, glass, car icons those i saw in Android Studio at start up !

Comment: @Sun Where at the start up you have seen ? Can you tell me in brief?

Comment: @Sun To get the start up screen again in your android studio. `Click on File Menu> New Module`. It will show you the similar pop up again.

Comment: @GrIsHu i know that what i asked, can i get all these icons that's it.. anyways thanks for efforts

Comment: @Sun Take screen shots of each icons thats it.

Comment: What about JRE? Do we need it? Is it also included in the section for JDK?

Comment: @MuhamedHuseinbašić JRE is included in JDK. you don't need to install it separately.

Comment: @GrIsHu - I am getting error `Error: Could not find or load main class com.intellij.idea.Main` once I run `./studio.sh` - any suggestions please?

Comment: `E: Invalid operation install` in `sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer`

Comment: The tar.gz file on the download of the release 2020.3.1.24-linux, not has a bin folder, this is a issue?

Answer (score 24):

Run the following command on terminal.

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:paolorotolo/android-studio
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install android-studio
```

Comment: Where would be the location of android SDK tools ?

Comment: yeah!! where did it all go? I got install success kinda msg?

Comment: @jeet.chanchawat I think it gets installed in /opt/android-studio

Comment: Ok, missed this link... thanks for the comment. I had to restart my machine and then I got it inside the listed apps. P.S: it take a lot of time to start for the first time. have a lot of patience.

Answer (score 8):

Don't forget to run:

> /opt/android-studio/bin/studio.sh

when you are done installing.

Comment: getting this err Unrecognized VM option 'MaxPermSize=350m'
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.

Comment: The question is how to install it in the first place. Imagine this was the only answer, would it make sense? No. Don't post half answers. If you have something to add to another answer, edit it in or post a comment there.

Answer (score 7):

The easiest method to install [Android Studio](https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html) (or any other developer tool) on Ubuntu is to use the [snap package](https://snapcraft.io/android-studio) from Ubuntu Software store. No need to download Android Studio as zip, try to manually install it, add PPAs or fiddle with Java installation. The snap package bundles the latest Android Studio along with OpenJDK and all the necessary dependencies.

##Step 1: Install Android Studio
Search *"android studio"* in Ubuntu Software, select the first entry that shows up and install it:

[image: Search Android Studio on Ubuntu Software]
[image: Android Studio on Ubuntu Software]

Or if you prefer the command line way, run this in *Terminal*:

```
sudo snap install --classic android-studio
```

##Step 2: Install Android SDK
Open the newly installed Android Studio from dashboard:

[image: Android Studio app on Dash]

Don't need to import anything if this is the first time you're installing it:

[image: Import Dialog]

The Setup Wizard'll guide you through installation:

[image: Android Studio Setup Wizard]

Select *Standard* install to get the latest SDK and *Custom* in-case you wanna change the SDK version or its install location. From here on, it's pretty straightforward, just click next-next and you'll have the SDK downloaded and installed.

[image: Select Standard or Custom installation]

##Step 3: Setting PATHs (Optional)
This step might be useful if you want Android SDK's developer tool commands like *adb*, *fastboot*, *aapt*, etc available in *Terminal*. Might be needed by 3rd party dev platforms like React Native, Ionic, Cordova, etc and other tools too. For setting PATHs, edit your `~/.profile` file:

```
gedit ~/.profile
```

and then add the following lines to it:

```
# Android SDK Tools PATH
export ANDROID_HOME=${HOME}/Android/Sdk
export PATH="${ANDROID_HOME}/tools:${PATH}"
export PATH="${ANDROID_HOME}/emulator:${PATH}"
export PATH="${ANDROID_HOME}/platform-tools:${PATH}"
```

If you changed SDK location at the end of Step 2, don't forget to change the line `export ANDROID_HOME=${HOME}/Android/Sdk` accordingly. Do a **restart** (or just logout and then log back in) for the PATHs to take effect.

---

Tested on Ubuntu 16.04LTS and above. Would work on 14.04LTS too if you [install support for snap packages first](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2017/02/install-snap-apps-ubuntu-14-04).

---

Note: This question is similar to the AskUbuntu question ["How to install Android Studio on Ubuntu?"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/634082/how-to-install-android-studio-on-ubuntu/) and [my answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/634082/how-to-install-android-studio-on-ubuntu/941222#941222) equally applies. I'm reproducing my answer here to ensure a full complete answer exists rather than just a link.

Answer (score 6):

Here's how I installed android studio on xubuntu.

**1. Install JDK:**

Go through following commands to install jdk

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install oracle-java7-installer
sudo apt-get install oracle-java7-set-default
```

If you want to install other version of jdk than replace your version number with 7 in last two commands.

**2. Download the latest android studio from official site:**
https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html

It is better to use latest version of android studio because I tried to install version 1.5.1 and it was not working. Then I installed version 2.1.1 and it run perfectly.

3. Extract downloaded android studio file in whichever folder you want.
   Now go to extracted android studio-->bin directory and open terminal        here. Now run following:

   ./studio.sh

And that's it. If you are facing any problem than comment below.

Answer (score 5):

You can also Install using a PPA 
[link](http://www.webupd8.org/2014/05/install-android-studio-in-ubuntu-via-ppa.html)

Comment: Yes I am using it. no issues.

Comment: even you install you will be getting updates from google only.

Comment: you mean this is perfect and has all the features of Android Studio, and can also write apps for tv as well ..

Comment: this is android studio. it has been hosted as ppa.

Comment: i have installed latest PPA release: https://github.com/PaoloRotolo/android-studio/releases but how to start android studio ?

Comment: type android studio in dash board

Comment: getting: OpenJDK 6 is not supported. Please use Oracle Java or newer OpenJDK

Comment: do you have jdk installed else install using this http://www.webupd8.org/2012/01/install-oracle-java-jdk-7-in-ubuntu-via.html

Comment: if you don't want oracle Java install open JDK 7 using this command sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jdk

Comment: thanks i have installed ! I marked your answer as useful

Comment: Installing using ppa failed, it couldn't find https://dl.google.com/dl/android/studio/ide-zips/2.1.0.9/android-studio-ide-143.2790544-linux.zip at one point.

Answer (score 5):

you can install android studio by following steps in the terminal :

1. sudo apt update
2. sudo apt install openjdk-8-jre
3. sudo add-apt-repository ppa:maarten-fonville/android-studio
4. sudo apt update
5. sudo apt install android-studio

make sure you have no error in installation.

Answer (score 3):

In order to install Android Studio on Ubuntu Studio 14.04 and derivatives, do the following:

Step 1: Open a terminal using the Dash or pressing `Ctrl + Alt + T` keys.

Step 2: If you have not, add that repository with the following command:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:paolorotolo/android-studio
```

Step 3: Update the APT with the command:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Step 4: Now install the program with the command:

```
sudo apt-get install android-studio
```

Step 5: Once installed, run the program by typing in Dash:

```
studio
```

Answer (score 3):

Android Studio is now integrated in **[JetBrains Toolbox](https://www.jetbrains.com/toolbox-app/)**:

This free tool allows to easily install all JetBrains products, and Android Studio as well. Upgrade is automatic.

[image: JetBrains toolbox]

On Ubuntu, this tools requires [FUSE](https://github.com/AppImage/AppImageKit/wiki/FUSE) (Filesystem in Userspace)

Answer (score 2):

Android Studio PPA is maintained by Paolo Rotolo. We just need to add PPA to our system and install it using the following commands:

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:paolorotolo/android-studio
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install android-studio
```

For more, see [allubuntu.com](http://allubuntu.com/install-android-studio-ubuntu/)

Comment: Same answer as @Elijah Keya

Answer (score 2):

To install android studio on ubuntu here is the simplest way possible:

First of all, you have to install Ubuntu Make before installing Android Studio. Type following commands in the same order one by one on terminal:

1) sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-desktop/ubuntu-make

2) sudo apt-get update

3) sudo apt-get install ubuntu-make

Now since you are done with Ubuntu make, use below command to install Android Studio:

4) umake android

While installation it will give you a couple of option which you can handle. So, Installation is done. You can open it and run an App of your choice. Isn’t it very easy? Let me know if you go through any problem, I can help.

Source [Install Android Studio](http://www.androidtutorialpoint.com/basics/how-to-install-android-studio-on-microsoft-windows-or-linux-unix-or-ubuntu-os/)

Answer (score 2):

Add a repository,

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:maarten-fonville/android-studio
sudo apt-get update
```

Then install using the command below:

```
sudo apt-get install android-studio
```

Answer (score 1):

Hi If you want to install android studio on ubuntu you shoudl first have Java JDk on ubuntu.
Installing Java SDK

First you have to install Oracle on Java 7 (JDK and JRE)

Download Java SDK 32 or 64 bit depending upon your version.

java sdk on ubuntu

Then extract the file in the /tmp folder.Al dialogue box will pop up, click on replace all.An error will also pop out click close.

Go to tmp folder,a new folder name jdk and version must be created.right click on the folder and then click on rename and copy the name of the folder.

Also read How to Install Genymotion on Ubuntu
First write this command and click enter.

install android sdk on ubuntu linux

```
sudo su
```

Then write this command and press enter

```
if [ ! -d '/usr/lib/jvm' ]; then mkdir /usr/lib/jvm; fi
```

Paste this command

```
mv /tmp/jdk1.8* /usr/lib/jvm/
```

jdk1.8* = replace it with the name of the extracted folder in this example =jdk1.8.0_05

and press enter

```
sdk install linux
```

java,javac,jar,javaws = we have to replace these

```
update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/java java /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8*/bin/java 1065
update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/javac javac /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8*/bin/javac 1065
update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/jar jar /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8*/bin/jar 1065
update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/javaws javaws /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8*/bin/javaws 1065
update-alternatives --config java
java -version
```

This was taken from
http://emulatorforpc.com/best-android-emulator-ubuntu/

Answer (score 0):

I was just investigating this issue now, you should use [Ubuntu Make](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-make)

Which "is a command line tool which allows you to download the latest version of popular developer tools on your installation"

Answer (score 0):

You could always follow the official guide on how to install Android Studio on Linux. There's even a video you can watch!

https://developer.android.com/studio/install.html

Remember to select Linux in the drop-down box.

[image: Screenshot of video]

To summarise the steps: download Android Studio and extract it and execute `studio.sh` to run it. If you're running 64-bit Ubuntu, you will need to run:

```
sudo apt-get install lib32z1 lib32ncurses5 lib32bz2-1.0 lib32stdc++6
```

Answer (score 0):

Follow the steps via terminal:

1. sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
2. sudo apt-get update
3. sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer

after then:

4. sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-set-default

then;

5. Download Android Studio from "https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html", use All Android Studio Packages.
6. Unzip the file.

At last type via terminal :

1. cd android-studio
2. cd bin
3. ./studio.sh

Then follow the commands and you're ready to go.

Answer (score 0):

I was having having an issue with umake being an outdated version. What fixed it was:

```
sudo apt remove --purge ubuntu-make
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-desktop/ubuntu-make
sudo apt update
sudo apt install ubuntu-make
umake android
```