# How to install Ionic framework on Ubuntu?

Tags: android, ionic-framework

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 version. I would like to use Ionic to build app for Android. I couldn't find exact solution to install Ionic.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

See the Cordova Platform Guide [here](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/5.1.1/guide_platforms_android_index.md.html#Android%20Platform%20Guide) and the Ionic Installation Guide [here](http://ionicframework.com/docs/guide/installation.html), but I'm highlighting the key steps for Ubuntu.

1. Install JDK 8. (This part was taken from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28314139/how-to-install-android-studio-in-ubuntu)).

   ```
   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer
   sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-set-default
   ```
2. Install node.js 0.12. [NodeSource install guide for Ubuntu and co.](https://nodesource.com/blog/nodejs-v012-iojs-and-the-nodesource-linux-repositories#installing-node-js-v0-12)
3. Install Android Studio and the Android SDK from [Google](https://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html). (I will refer to the folder where you install as `where-you-unpacked-the-sdk` later.)
4. Using a terminal, install the Ionic CLI and related tools.

   ```
   sudo apt-get install git ruby
   sudo gem install compass
   sudo npm install -g cordova ionic grunt-cli bower gulp
   ```
5. Add the Android SDK to your PATH and set the ANDROID_HOME environment variable correctly. Using `~/.bash_profile` for this is the usual approach.

   ```
   echo "export ANDROID_HOME=/where-you-unpacked-the-sdk/sdk" >> ~/.bash_profile
   echo "export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools" >> ~/.bash_profile
   source ~/.bash_profile
   ```
6. Start using Ionic!

   ```
   ionic start todo example
   cd example
   ionic platform add android
   ionic run android
   ```

Comment: You can always use the script I wrote as well https://blog.nraboy.com/2014/09/install-android-cordova-ionic-framework-ubuntu/

Comment: Excellent answer. Really helpful

Comment: Also for Ubuntu 16.04, sudo apt-get install ruby-dev

Answer (score 8):

Go to github clone the link to your directory:
[ https://github.com/nraboy/ubuntu-ionic-installer ]

`git clone https://github.com/nraboy/ubuntu-ionic-installer`

after cloning, go to the directory - ubuntu-ionic-installer:

`cd ubuntu-ionic-installer`

`chmod 775 ubuntu_ionic_installer.sh`

`sudo ./ubuntu_ionic_installer.sh`

Then get coffee and relax until the install is done 
you can

to check just type 
`ionic`
in the terminal

Comment: Please don't post exact copy/pastes of previous [answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32224111/ionic-installation-in-ubuntu/35528732#35528732). Instead, customize each answer to the question being asked to help the OP and others in the future.

Answer (score 3):

### IONIC2 beta installation

**Step 1:** All basic installation in one step,

https://github.com/nraboy/ubuntu-ionic-installer

**Step 2:** But above link give old version of nodeJS. So uninstall nodejs.

```
$ apt-get remove nodejs
```

**Step 3: Then Install latest version of nodeJs**

```
$ sudo apt-get install curl
$ curl --silent --location https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_5.x | sudo bash -
$ sudo apt-get install nodejs
```

**Step 4: Install latest NVM - nodejs verions manager**

```
$ sudo apt-get install build-essential libssl-dev
$ curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.31.0/install.sh | bash
```

**Step 5: Important Note**

Here you'll need to restart your bash session in order to get nvm loaded - available on path (close / open terminal).

**Step 7:**

```
$ nvm install 5.4.1
$ nvm use 5.4.1

$ node --version
  v5.4.1
$ npm --version
  3.3.12
```

**Step 8 Then finally install ionic2 beta version (don`t forget sudo)**

```
$ sudo npm install -g ionic@beta
$ ionic --version
  2.0.0-beta.17
```

I give this answer based on these links,

https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ionic2-installation-on-ubuntu-14-04/41183/3

http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/getting-started/installation/

**Note:** I am at beginnerlevel of ubuntu environment & also ionic environment.so this answer may be contains mistakes.If any mistakes correct me.

Comment: I thought ionic does not work with nodejs 5 [source](http://ionicframework.com/getting-started/)

Comment: @irajjelodari if any wrong correct for future user.. or give suggestion.. because I successfully installed using above steps.. but not used still now. so may be wrong in this answer..

Answer (score 2):

As Others have stated: Install the following:

- Java (oracle 8+)
- Ant
- git
- node
- android sdk (may need lib32)
- cordova
- ionic itself
- bower, grunt, gulp

So Java+git+abt first:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer
sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-set-default
sudo apt-get install ant git
```

choose an Node version:

```
#0.12
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_0.12 | sudo bash -
```

or

```
#5.x
https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_5.x
```

eitherway:

```
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```

If you're on an x64 machine:

```
sudo apt-get install ia32-libs lib32ncurses5-dev lib32stdc++6
```

if ia32-libs+lib32ncurses5 are not found use:

```
sudo apt-get install lib32z1 lib32ncurses5 lib32bz2-1.0 lib32stdc++6
```

Next: Android Sdk
Download AndroidStudio/ or Standalone Sdk. I would recommend Studio, as it simplifies the installation-process a lot

- download from [Android.com](https://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/index.html)
- unzip to arbitrary location
- run studio.sh (in /XY-location/Android-Sdk_linux/bin)
- Add SDK to PATH: append to ~/.bash_profile or ~/.profile

  export ANDROID_HOME=/home/xyx/Android/sdk
  export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools

Finally install the node modules

```
sudo npm install -g gulp bower grunt-cli cordova
```

And ionic

```
sudo npm install -g ionic
```

or for ionic v2 (still in alpha state but cool++)

```
sudo npm install -g ionic@alpha
```