# How to install Android Studio on Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: android-studio

I am trying to install Android Studio on my Ubuntu 14.04 machine. I downloaded android-studio tar file from official website.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to install Android Studio in Ubuntu](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28314139/how-to-install-android-studio-in-ubuntu)

Answer (score 0):

After Downloading the Tar files do the following steps:

```
sudo tar xvzf android-studio-ide-135.1641136-linux.zip
cd android-studio-ide-135.1641136-linux
./studio.sh
```