# Android emulator startup issues in VirtualBox running Ubuntu

Tags: android, linux, ubuntu, virtualbox, android-virtual-device

Ubuntu: Desktop 14.04 (64-bit)
VirtualBox: Version 5.0.16 r105871
Android SDK: 24.4.1

I am trying to get Android Emulator running on Ubuntu 14 (Trusty Tahir).

1. I first downloaded and installed Ubuntu 14 in a new Virtualbox VM.
2. Downloaded and installed OpenJDK (apt-get openjdk-7-jdk).
3. Downloaded and untar-ed the android sdk archive.
4. Navigated to android-sdk-linux/tools/  and ran ./android
5. Android SDK manager, pulled SDK build revision 19 (for Android 4.x) and 23 (for Android 6).
6. After all the packages have been downloaded and installed, i launch Android SDK Manager once more, and click Tools > AVD Manager.
7. Created a new Nexus5 / Google Nexus AVD. Click 'Start'.

This is when I see the following errors:

```
Starting emulator for AVD 'AspectClass'
pci id for fd 5: 80ee:beef, driver (null)
libGL error: core dri or dri2 extension not found
libGL error: failed to load driver: vboxvideo
pci id for fd 8: 80ee:beef, driver (null)
libGL error: core dri or dri2 extension not found
libGL error: failed to load driver: vboxvideo
emulator: WARNING: Classic qemu does not support SMP. The hw.cpu.ncore option from your config file is ignored.
emulator: WARNING: The -scale flag is obsolete and will be ignored.
```

My research into a couple of these errors like the core dri/dri2 lead me to resources that indicate  this might have something to do with 3D acceleration setting in Virtualbox. This does not apply to my case since I have 3D acceleration setting disabled.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You are trying to run the emulator (a virtual machine) inside another virtual machine? Just run Android Studio on your host OS

Answer (score 1):

1) Make sure u have latest Android Studio 2.0, update java sdk version to 8

2) start emulator from android studio, if any issues. restart ubuntu,

3) go to boot option usually by pressing F12(or)F2, there enable fast virtual machine option and save and exit. Also enable the same option fast virtual mode in Virtual box VM if any.

4) After login start Emulator from Android Studio. Thats it

Android studio 2.0 has so many improvements http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html

Comment: Thanks @pavan-kvch  - I tried following the steps you mentioned. OpenJDK has no official release for Ubuntu 14.04 unfortunately. Also, when I tried to launch the AVD Manager from Android Studio, it kept throwing an error saying "your cpu doesn't support required features (vt-x or svm)". Thoughts?

Comment: @raTM follow this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28314139/how-to-install-android-studio-in-ubuntu

Comment: Thank you once again, @pavan-kvch. I tried the options listed in the answers from the SO page you linked me to. None of them seemed to make this go away. Ultimately I had to perform the following steps:


1.  Install Intel HAXM
2. Add the following line to my VMX file: vhv.enable = "TRUE"