# Android development software for ubuntu linux

Tags: android

I currently moved from windows to ubuntu-linux. So I want to know what would be the best software for making android applications aside from android-studio for ubuntu-linux OS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use android studio, you can get it following [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28314139/how-to-install-android-studio-in-ubuntu)

If you don't want to use android studio for some reason.. you can use [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org)