# How to install Android sdk to Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: android

I had download Android zip file from the web site developer.android.com

And I try to install like following command in Terminal.

```
#cd desktop/android-sdk/tools/

#./studio.sh
```

After this system shows the window with title Android SDK Manager

Is it the proper procedure to install?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use apt-get to install , its easier.

1st) Download the repository

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:paolorotolo/android-studio
```

2nd) Update

```
sudo apt-get update
```

3rd) install

```
sudo apt-get install android-studio
```

this will install a old version , you just have to update .
If you plan to run adb command you have to set the path on your .bashrc "OR" .profile.

```
export ANDROID_HOME=~/Android/Sdk

PATH=\$PATH:\$ANDROID_HOME:\$ANDROID_HOME/tools:\$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools
export PATH
```

you can create a desktop entry form Android Studio , in case you don't find how to create you can create by creating a file:

```
/usr/share/applications/android-studio.desktop
```

inside this file add this lines

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Terminal=false
Name=Android Studio
Exec=/opt/android-studio/bin/studio.sh
Comment=Integrated Android developer tools for development and debugging.
Icon=androidstudio
Categories=GNOME;GTK;Development;IDE;
```

i create a script to do all this job but unfortunately i cant send it here.
PS: make sure you have the JAVA_HOME set .

Answer (score 0):

[How to install Android Studio in Ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28314139/how-to-install-android-studio-in-ubuntu)

Duplicate Question is why you are being voted down a simple google search of

android studio on ubuntu 14.04 top result is a referenced question that is protected here

Answer (score 0):

Setting up Android Studio takes just a few clicks.

While the [Android Studio download](https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html) completes, verify which version of the JDK you have: open a command line and type javac -version. If the JDK is not available or the version is lower than 1.8, download the [Java SE Development Kit 8](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html).

To install Android Studio on Linux, proceed as follows:

1. Unpack the `.zip` file you downloaded to an appropriate location for
   your applications, such as within `/usr/local/` for your user profile,
   or `/opt/` for shared users.
2. To launch Android Studio, open a terminal, navigate to the
   `android-studio/bin/ directory`, and execute `studio.sh`. Tip: Add
   `android-studio/bin/` to your `PATH` environment variable so you can
   start Android Studio from any directory.
3. Select whether you want to import previous Android Studio settings
   or not, then click OK.
4. The Android Studio Setup Wizard guides you though the rest of the
   setup, which includes downloading Android SDK components that are
   required for development.

Note: If you are running a 64-bit version of Ubuntu, you need to install some 32-bit libraries with the following command:

`sudo apt-get install lib32z1 lib32ncurses5 lib32bz2-1.0 lib32stdc++6`

If you are running 64-bit Fedora, the command is:

`sudo yum install zlib.i686 ncurses-libs.i686 bzip2-libs.i686`

Find the Instructions for install Android Studio for Linux from [this link](https://developer.android.com/studio/install.html)
All the information is there, yet feel free to ask anything.