# How to download the complete sdk tools for eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk

I am facing an issue to download the complete sdk tools for the android.

I downloaded and installed eclipse mars in my ubuntu 14.04.

I downloaded the sdk from https://dl.google.com/android/android-sdk_r24.4.1-linux.tgz

But it dont have all the tools that I need, so I installed studio and downloaded all the tools that I require.

Then when I tried to add `appcompat` I am unable to add that to my eclipse.
The documentation saying that appcompat should be at \extras\android\support\v7\appcompat
But it was at /extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/appcompat-v7.

Finally I want to add that appcomat to my project.
How can I do that?
I dont want to go with studio, I want to use eclipse mars.

Comment: Eclipse is out dated for android development, **Use Android Studio**

Comment: Is using android studio simpler than eclipse? I have complete eclipse project with me, I just add that to eclipse and I can start work(only issue adding that appcompat). But now using android studio means starting from the beginning

Comment: stop using eclipse, you can migrate your eclipse projects to android studio via android studio

Comment: I can't say if it is simpler or not. But it is good to work with. Check [this](https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/migrate.html) to know how to migrate your eclipse project to android studio. **Note: Keep a back up of your project** :)

Comment: Use Android Studio. For Ubuntu check this link... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28314139/how-to-install-android-studio-in-ubuntu

Comment: Support for the Android Developer Tools (ADT) Eclipse plugin ended ~10 months ago. There has not been an ADT-compatible `appcompat-v7` published in quite some time.

Comment: Hmm, Ok. I migrated to studio, but how to add that. I am getting error `Error:(56) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar'.`